# Service Worker not working for Mobile Web (Chrome, Firefox, IE)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, webpack-2, service-worker

I set up a service worker for a static web application that needs to work on mobile phones. I'm using react/webpack2 for this application.

Service Worker installs and works greatly when I open the application via desktop, but when I try to visit the application through mobile, it does not install. 
When SW finishes installing, it gives you an alert message ("onInstalled");

https://abo-deg.surge.sh (here is an example)

https://abo-deg.surge.sh/survey/background

https://github.com/strongharris/sample (sw.js located inside src, main entrypoint: src/index.js, webpack.config)

The alert message shows up via desktop, but not on mobile browsers.
Am I missing something? Is there a different way to set up a service worker for mobile web applications? Any resources, or tips, or guesses would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is pretty simple. Your server does not automatically transfer you to `https://abo-deg.surge.sh` when you type `abo-deg.surge.sh` on your mobile.

I was able to run it on Chrome Mobile by typing full URL with https://

Service worker API is available only for websites running over HTTPS, because

> Having modified network requests wide open to man in the middle attacks would be really bad
>    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

Please keep in mind, that your code will work only on [these browsers](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/), so don't expect it to work on iOS