# Service worker not registering on mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, push-notification

I want to implement push notifications for my domain on desktop and mobile. On desktop everything works as expected and I'm able to send pushes from my server to the test devices.

On Chrome for Android, I'm not even able to register the service worker. I have tested the following code on OnePlus 3 and Huawei Mate 9 which are recent and powerful devices and I actually receive web notifications on them.

This is the code I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
    alert('best');
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
       navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
          alert('test');
       });
    });
}
</script>
```

The first alert pops so the browser supports service workers and push notifications. The second one for some reason doesn't pop on mobile chrome but works on desktop chrome! Am I missing something?

The code resides on a page called `test.php`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change "./sw.js". Because if you dont use dot, it means located in root of your server

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `./` before the file name and instead simply using the file name `sw.js`. I too was having the same issues, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024738/service-worker-not-working-for-mobile-web-chrome-firefox-ie) will help